# Prove intersection is ${0_v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I asking this question because I'm not sure how to prove it exactly.

Let $B$ be a basis of vector space $V$ , $B=B_1∪B_2$. so $U_1=span{B_1}$ and $U_2=span{B_2}$.

I need to show that $U_1∩U_2 = 0_v$.
I assume there is a vector $v∈U_1∩U_2$ such that $v≠0_v$.
because $v∈U_1∩U_2$ then $v∈U_1 ∧ v∈U_2$.
$\implies$ $v$ can be written as linear equation of $U_1$ and $U_2$. $\implies$ $v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n = c_1v_1+...+c_mv_m$
when $U_1=span(v_1,...,v_n) , U_2=span({v_1,...,v_m})$
which means we have a common vector between $U_1$ and $U_2$ so $B$ is lineary dependent which contradicts the fact that it isn't (We can take the scalars to be equal to $v$ and $-v$ and then not all scalars are 0 $\implies$ not independent).

Comment: What do we know about $B_1$ and $B_2$? What if $B_1=B_2=B$, then this is obviously wrong, so an assumption has to be made for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. You wrote that $U_1=U_2=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$, which is not true. The set $U_1$ is spanned by *some* vectors $v_{n_1},v_{n_2}\ldots,v_{n_k}$, with $n_1,\ldots,n_k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $n_1<\cdots<n_k$. And the set $U_2$ is spanned by $v_{m_1},\ldots,v_{m_l}$, with$$\{m_1,\ldots,m_l\}=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{{n_1},{n_2}\ldots,{n_k}\}.$$So, if$$v=\alpha_{n_1}v_{n_1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n_k}v_{n_k}=\alpha_{m_1}v_{m_1}+\cdots+\alpha_{m_k}v_{m_k}$$and $v\ne0$, then not all $\alpha$'s are $0$, but$$0=v-v=\alpha_{n_1}v_{n_1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n_k}v_{n_k}-\alpha_{m_1}v_{m_1}-\cdots-\alpha_{m_k}v_{m_k},$$which is impossible, since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: oh right , this is what I wanted to write as the indexes but got confused,  Thank you.